# confusing with JMP instruction

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

I write an inline assembly program to unlink **"grades.txt"** in **/home/httpd**, here is the code:

```
void main()
{
   __asm__(
   "jmp L\n"\
   "sub1:\n"\
   "movl 0x4(%esp), %ebx\n"\
   "movb $0xa, %al\n"\
   "int $0x80\n"\
   "L:\n"\
   "call sub1\n"\
   ".string \"//home//httpd//grades.txt\" "
   );
}
```

I think the code shall do what I want, to unlink the grades.txt in "/home/httpd", yet when I execute it, there is a segment fault.

And I use gdb to tackle this fault, I found that it can't execute the line "jmp L", the program will stop when in line 5 ["__asm__("] until I enter "ctrl + c" to interrupt it.

If I add the assembly of "exit(0)" to let the program exit cleanly , and continue execute it, the program will just exit without doing anything.

so this is quite confusing, **why the program doesn't execute the jmp instruction?** Is there any errors?

I shall very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Is `call sub1` a typo for `call subl` or is this an error in the code?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake when typing the code on the web page, on my machine both are `call sub1`. I will modify it.

Comment: It is not `jmp L` that causes SIGSEGV. It's `movl 0x4(%esp), %ebx`. Is the target x86 or x64? I suspect your target is x64. If this is the case then you should use rsp instead of esp.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my target is x86.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

- You should use `%eax` instead of `%al` because the 3 most significant bytes can be not `000000`
- The `movl 0x4(%esp), %ebx` line should be `movl (%esp), %ebx` because `%ebp` is not pushed onto the stack hence return address is at `%esp+0`
- After doinig `int 80h` the code will fall through and call `sub1` over and over again, so you need an extra jump:

  ```
  int80h
  add $4, %esp # pop the return address
  jmp exit     # jump over the call
  call sub1
  ....
  exit:
  ```
- No need to use `\` - the strings will be concatenated for you
- `void` is not a valid return type for `main()` in C

Summing up the above tips:

```
int main()
{
   __asm__(
   "jmp L\n"
   "sub1:\n"
   "movl (%esp), %ebx\n"
   "movl $0xa, %eax\n"
   "int $0x80\n"
   "add $4, %esp\n"
   "jmp exit\n"
   "L:\n"
   "call sub1\n"
   ".string \"//home//httpd//grades.txt\"\n"
   "exit:\n"
   );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now the problem is solved!!  :) Thank you so much!!